# Decipher handwriting in Spanish Birth Certificate

Tags: palaeography, spain

DeepL translation:

I need to decipher the marked words to continue with my family tree. In the first image the first name could be Fabricio, Sabino or Patricio but I don't know for sure. The second word is the name of an Asturian town I think in the council of Grado that is preceded by San Juan (another town) and .... And finally in the second image I identify Emilio Alvarez but I can't understand the second surname.

Original message:

Necesito descrifrar las palabras marcadas para proseguir con mi árbol genealógico. Si me pueden ayudar se lo agradezco mucho. En la primera imágen el primer nombre puede ser Fabricio, Sabino o Patricio pero no lo sé con certeza. La segunda palabra es el nombre de una localidad asturiana creo que del concejo de Grado que viene precedido de San Juan (otra localidad) y ... Y por último en la segunda imágen identifico Emilio Álvarez pero no logro entender el segundo apellido. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo al que quiera ayudarme. Un saludo

[image]
[image]

Comment: A possibility for the second surname is Gracia, Emilio Alvarez Gracia. Could you post a photo of the first shot showing the whole line, to give some context. (It seems to me it is a parish name but more text may help).

Comment: I think it might be Grana since its a very common surname there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "Sabrina" or "Sabina".
In 2nd image it says "Que es hija de"  (feminine)

Also in top image, I think it says something like (de S Juan y S Tirne).
Things are obscured a little by the long descender of the 'y' from the line   where it says something like: "Sabrina Alvares y Josefe"